# Problem in generating the border of a rectangle in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I am using [java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html) class to generate a rectangle. I want to generate a rectangle which is filled with a color (say green) and have a border (outline).

Now the problem is if I call

```
g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(....)); // g2 is an instance of Graphics2D
```

then it doesn't fill the rectangle and when I call

```
g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(....)); // g2 is an instance of Graphics2D
```

then id doesn't generate border.

Comment: Dan and Samuel are both right. It's logical too. `fill` fills the entire rectangular area, including the area occupied by the border you just drew. Time to pull your foot out of the line of fire :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about doing both?  Draw the filled rectangle first and then draw the outline one over the top.

Answer (score 11):

To do this, render the rectangle twice, first the fill and then the border (draw).

```
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(...);
g2.setColor(Color.white);
g2.fill(rect);
g2.setColor(Color.black);
g2.draw(rect);
```